# Сломался перевод в тревоге "должен быть закрыт"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия

Заголовки не переведены в "Тревога" -> "Должен быть закрыт"

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Увидел вопрос на английском, захотелось закрыть, а там _"Off-topic because..."_, теперь рука не поднимается :)

Comment: Выкатили [обновления по выделению вопросов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide). Также перевод сломался по всем закрытым вопросам: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1054930/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c)

Comment: @defaultlocale, в [удаленных тоже](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAqXJ.png)

Comment: На ru.meta.stackoverflow.com - так же само поламался.

Comment: И traducir.win лежит мёртвый. Отписался им на гитхабе уже.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Он не мертвый, проделки РосКомНадзора. Скорее всего, из-за того, что на том же IP был какой-то сайт, имеющий проблемы с законом. Надо бы писать туда, где принимают жалобы на несправедливую блокировку, а не на гитхаб.

Comment: @MSDN.'ReinstateMonica'Knight видимо, лояльность моего оператора немного изменилась. Жалобу, кмк, должен менеджер сообщества накатать. А на гитхабе всё-таки тоже полезно, чтоб знали.

Comment: Теперь и в мобильном приложении сломалось.

Answer (score 1):

Принял предложения от [MSDN.Knight](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/240512) и добавил старый вариант переводов, где нужно было. Выкатится с новым обновлением движка.

Comment: Да ну, раньше лучше было...

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica не помню, какие раньше варианты были)

Comment: <q>Необходимо переформулировать чтобы можно было дать объективный ответ. Не понятна суть вопроса. Дубликат</q>. Был еще какой то...